# nested form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, form-for

I have the project organized in this way: User is the main resource, each user has one profile and each profile has one location as following:

```
 resources :users do    
    resource :profile, :controller => "profiles" do
      resource :location
end
```

Now I have to build a form for insert all the profile information but the location information as well (address etc).
If I write the following code, it doesn't take care about the location.

```
<%= form_for(@profile, :url=>{:action=>'update'}, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

Do someone have some suggestion for this situation ?

Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access different models within the same form you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Here is a great screencast about the topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Your code should something like this.

```
#profile.rb

accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
```

In your view:

```
<%= form_for(@profile, :url=>{:action=>'update'}, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :location do |l| %>
     //location fields here, for example:
     <%=l.text_field :city %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

use :

```
form_for [@user, @profile, @location], :action => :update, :html => {:multipart => true}
```

Comment: form_for [@user, @profile, @location], :action => :update, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| f.textfield :location ???????????

Comment: Is it possible to access to the first_name of the profile and to the address of the location in the same form_for ? If yes, how ? Give me an example please. Tnx